# Confused on how to get this LinkedList function to run

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I have the class below from one of the textbooks I am using. Everything makes sense to me except for how exactly i'm supposed to use any of the functions that take **IPosition** as a paremeter **EX**: before() and addBefore() functions

if IPosition is a interface thats implemented inside a private nested Node class how can I use those functions if for example I want to add some new data using the addBefore() function in a list of 100 items?

```
public class LinkedPositionalList <E> implements IPositionalList<E>{
    private static class Node<E> implements IPosition<E> {
        private E element; // reference to the element stored at this node
        private Node<E> prev; // reference to the previous node in the list
        private Node<E> next; // reference to the subsequent node in the list
        public Node(E e, Node<E> p, Node<E> n) {
            element = e;
            prev = p;
            next = n;
        }
        public E getElement() throws IllegalStateException {
            if (next == null) // convention for defunct node
                throw new IllegalStateException("Position no longer valid");
            return element;
        }
        public Node<E> getPrev() {
            return prev;
        }
        public Node<E> getNext() {
            return next;
        }
        public void setElement(E e) {
            element = e;
        }
        public void setPrev(Node<E> p) {
            prev = p;
        }
        public void setNext(Node<E> n) {
            next = n;
        }
    }

    private Node<E> header; // header sentinel
    private Node<E> trailer; // trailer sentinel
    private int size = 0; // number of elements in the list
    public LinkedPositionalList( ) {
        header = new Node<>(null, null, null); // create header
        trailer = new Node<>(null, header, null); // trailer is preceded by header
        header.setNext(trailer); // header is followed by trailer
    }
    private Node<E> validate(IPosition<E> p) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (!(p instanceof Node)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid p");
        Node<E> node = (Node<E>) p; // safe cast
        if (node.getNext( ) == null) {// convention for defunct node
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("p is no longer in the list");
        }
        return node;
    }

    private IPosition<E> position(Node<E> node) {
        if (node == header || node == trailer) {
            return null; // do not expose user to the sentinels
        }
        return node;
    }

    public int size() { return size; }

    public boolean isEmpty() { return size == 0; }

    public IPosition<E> first() {
        return position(header.getNext());
    }
    public IPosition<E> last() {
        return position(trailer.getPrev());
    }

    public IPosition<E> before(IPosition<E> p) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Node<E> node = validate(p);
        return position(node.getPrev());
    }

    public IPosition<E> after(IPosition<E> p) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Node<E> node = validate(p);
        return position(node.getNext());
    }

    private IPosition<E> addBetween(E e, Node<E> pred, Node<E> succ) {
        Node<E> newest = new Node<>(e, pred, succ); // create and link a new node
        pred.setNext(newest);
        succ.setPrev(newest);
        size++;
        return newest;
    }

    public IPosition<E> addFirst(E e) {
        return addBetween(e, header, header.getNext( )); // just after the header
    }

    public IPosition<E> addLast(E e) {
        return addBetween(e, trailer.getPrev( ), trailer); // just before the trailer
    }

    public IPosition<E> addBefore(IPosition<E> p, E e) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Node<E> node = validate(p);
        return addBetween(e, node.getPrev( ), node);
    }

    public IPosition<E> addAfter(IPosition<E> p, E e) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            Node<E> node = validate(p);
            return addBetween(e, node, node.getNext( ));
    }

    public E set(IPosition<E> p, E e) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Node<E> node = validate(p);
        E answer = node.getElement( );
        node.setElement(e);
        return answer;
    }

    public E remove(IPosition<E> p) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Node<E> node = validate(p);
        Node<E> predecessor = node.getPrev( );
        Node<E> successor = node.getNext( );
        predecessor.setNext(successor);
        successor.setPrev(predecessor);
        size--;
        E answer = node.getElement( );
        node.setElement(null); // help with garbage collection
        node.setNext(null); // and convention for defunct node
        node.setPrev(null);
        return answer;
    }
}

public interface IPosition<E> {
    E getElement( ) throws IllegalStateException;
}

public interface IPositionalList <E>{
    int size();
    boolean isEmpty();
    IPosition<E> first();
    IPosition<E> last();
    IPosition<E> before(IPosition<E> p) throws IllegalArgumentException;
    IPosition<E> after(IPosition<E> p) throws IllegalArgumentException;
    IPosition<E> addFirst(E e);
    IPosition<E> addLast(E e);
    IPosition<E> addBefore(IPosition<E> p, E e) throws IllegalArgumentException;
    IPosition<E> addAfter(IPosition<E> p, E e) throwsIllegalArgumentException;
    E set(IPosition<E> p, E e) throws IllegalArgumentException;
    E remove(IPosition<E> p) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

Comment: vtc reason: Code does not include the definition of IPosition.

Comment: @rzwitserloot sorry just updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IPosition` is simply the public API variant of `Node` in this case - a somewhat common if dubious exercise.

How do you make an instance of this type? You don't. You call something that gets you such a thing and then pass it along. For example, `first()`, which returns an object whose type hierarchy contains at least IPosition.

For example:

```
void test() {
  IPositionalList<String> list = new LinkedPositionalList<>();

  list.addLast("Hello");
  list.addLast("World");
  IPosition<String> first = list.first();
  list.addAfter(first, "there");
}
```

list would contain [Hello, there, World].

NB: Making one interface for every class is discouraged, especially public classes; `IPosition<E>` is possibly defensible, `IPositionalList` is not, given that LinkedPositionalList is public.

NB2: Naming your interfaces `IFoo`, a kind of weird hungarian notation, is extremely archiac and strongly discouraged; your IDE can tell you if you really must know if something is an interface or not; more generally it doesn't matter. It gets in the way of refactors; what if later you change your mind and take what used to a class and make it an interface, or vice versa? Do you break even more by adding or removing that `I`? Are enums going to be named `ESuit` instead of just `Suit`, records `RPerson` instead of Person, should abstract classes get an A? What about annotation interfaces? Why don't we call `public static strictfp int getFoo()` instead `psfiGetFoo`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer and extra advice. I am new to Java and the naming standard was what I was taught through some videos. but what you are saying makes sense, thank you